# Schematic input does not validate against the Schema

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm having this error when I try to create a new component anywhere inside the project:

```
PS C:\Users\Name\Documents\Project\project-app\src\app\modals> ng g c especificacaoTecnicaModal
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"path":"/src/app/modals","displayBlock":false,"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","style":"css","type":"Component","skipTests":false,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"skipSelector":false,"export":false}
Errors:

  Data path "" should have required property 'name'.
```

Here is my `ng --version`

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.4
Node: 14.17.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        12.0.4
@angular/animations               12.0.4
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               12.0.4
@schematics/update                <error>
rxjs                              6.0.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

It started when I was installing angular material. If I try to run `ng serve` or `ng build --prod --base-href ./` it run normally. If you need more data just comment it and I'll answer.

Comment: Looks like the versions are not matching with your cli version. CLI version says 6, and the schematics, devkit schematics and animations are v12.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Adithya Sreyaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10781739/adithya-sreyaj), the erros was only in @schematics/angular so I ran `npm i @schematics/angular@0.7.5` and then I could create a new component

##### Now My `ng --version` looks like this:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 14.17.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
@angular/animations               7.2.0
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      6.1.5
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.7.5
rxjs                              6.0.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

My @angular/animations changed but I don't think I really needed to change it